# Regarding clear history on click of logout button in phonegap android using cordova 2.7.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

hy is there any method or line of code to exactly remove all history as i have "logout" button in my app clicking on loggedout buttoon its exactly log out the current user and page changes to "login page " but when i reached to login page and trying to hit "device BACK button" it go back to previous page   which is wrong . the application should not move back once he is loggedout so how can i overcome into this problem  kindly suggest any code to resolve this issue?

here is the code of "loggedout" button :

```
$('#logoutButton').off("click").on("click", function () {
        $("#pass").val("");
        window.localStorage.setItem("userid", null);

      $.mobile.changePage("#login",null,true,true);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeitem` method instead setting `null` value. Change this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("userid", null);
```

to this:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("userid");
```

When page initializes and loads, check status value of `localstorage`. If that is `null`, then return to login page:

```
$( "#xyz-page" ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {
  if(localStorage['userid']==null)
      $.mobile.changePage("#login",null,true,true);
});
```

Comment: but my problem is after login page my app should remove history .... when i came to login page and click on back button then it s showing me back history which is wrong